# How to unify (collapse) multiple columns into one assigning unique values

Tags: python, pandas

Edited my previous question:

Want to distinguish each Devices (FOUR types) that are attached to a particular Building's particular Elevator (represented by height).

1. As there is no unique IDs for the devices, want to identify them and assign unique IDs to each of them by Grouping ('BldID', 'BldHt', 'Deivce') to identify any particular 'Device'.
2. Count their testing results, i.e. how many times it failed (NG) out of total number of testing (NG + OK) for any particular date for the entire duration consisting of few months.

Original dataframe looks like this

```
BldgID   BldgHt  Device   Date        Time   Result
1074     34.0    790      2018/11/20   10:30  OK
1072     31.0    780      2018/11/19   11:10  NG
1072     36.0    780      2018/11/17   05:30  OK
1074     10.0    790      2018/11/19   06:10  OK   
1074     10.0    790      2018/12/20   11:50  NG
1076     17.0    760      2018/08/15   09:20  NG
1076     17.0    760      2018/09/20   13:40  OK
```

As 'Time' is irrelevant, dropped it. Want to find the number of [NG]  per day for each set (consists of 'BldgID', 'BlgHt', 'Device'].

```
#aggregate both functions only once by groupby
 df1 = mel_df.groupby(['BldgID','BldgHt','Device','Date'])\
['Result'].agg([('NG', lambda x :(x=='NG').sum()), \
('ALL','count')]).round(2).reset_index()

 #create New_ID by insert with Series with zero fill 3 values
 s = pd.Series(np.arange(1, len(mel_df2) + 1), 
 index=mel_df2.index).astype(str).str.zfill(3)
 mel_df2.insert(0, 'New_ID', s)
```

Now the filtered DataFrame looks like:

```
 print (mel_df2)
    New_ID  BldgID  BldgHt  Device  Date        NG   ALL
 1   001    1072    31.0    780     2018/11/19   1    2
 8   002    1076    17.0    760     2018/11/20   1    1
```

If I groupby ['BldgID', 'BldgHt', 'Device', 'Date'] then I get per day 'NG'. 
But it would consider every day differently and if I assign 'unique' IDs I can plot how the unique Devices behave in every other single day.

If I groupby ['BldgId', 'BldgHt', 'Device'] then I get the overall 'NG' for that set (or unique Device), which is not my goal.

```
 What I want to achieve is:

 print (mel_df2)

 New_ID  BldgID  BldgHt Device   Date        NG   ALL
 001    1072    31.0    780      2018/11/19   1    2
        1072    31.0    780      2018/12/30   3    4
 002    1076    17.0    760      2018/11/20   1    1
        1076    17.0    760      2018/09/20   2    4 
 003    1072    36.0    780      2018/08/15   1    3
```

Any tips would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain more `2018/11/18  2   4` and `2018/10/20  2   6` ? Mainly last 2 numbers?

Comment: 'ALL' means total number of test done. 'NG' means number of times it failed. So these 2    6 means out of 6 tries, 2 times it failed and other 4 times it was 'OK'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#aggregate both aggregate function only in once groupby
df1 = mel_df.groupby(['BldgID','BldgHt','Device','Date'])\
    ['Result'].agg([('NG', lambda x :(x=='NG').sum()), ('ALL','count')]).round(2).reset_index()

#filter non 0 rows
mel_df2 = df1[df1.NG != 0]

#filter first rows by Date
mel_df2 = mel_df2.drop_duplicates('Date')

#create New_ID by insert with Series with zero fill 3 values
s = pd.Series(np.arange(1, len(mel_df2) + 1), index=mel_df2.index).astype(str).str.zfill(3)
mel_df2.insert(0, 'New_ID', s)
```

Output from data from question:

```
print (mel_df2)
  New_ID  BldgID  BldgHt Device        Date  NG  ALL
1    001    1072    31.0    780  2018/11/19   1    1
8    002    1076    17.0    780  2018/11/20   1    1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Also, for the unifying the two functions that I did in an inefficient way. I guess there must be some efficient method, but could not find.

Comment: @jezrale Is it possible to make the 'New_ID' considering 'BldgID', 'BldgHt', 'Device' and count the number of 'NG' for any particular day? So that for the same 'New_ID' can count num of 'NG' for another day. There are one/multiple tests on a single day.  Now, as the day is also included, every other day with other values are same, producing a 'New_ID'. Would like to assign 'New_ID' with the first 3 Indexes.

Comment: @Fakir - Yes, then need [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) like change `pd.Series(np.arange(1, len(mel_df2) + 1), index=mel_df2.index)` to `mel_df.groupby(['BldgID','BldgHt','Device'], sort=False).ngroup().add(1)`

Comment: Thanks. Assigning a 'New_ID' for the 1st 3 as a group could be done as in the previous method?